# In a math problem, what does the word "long" refer to?

Tags: word-usage

For example:

> Bill drives 346 miles from home to the beach. He stops for lunch after driving 180 miles. How **long** does it take him to drive the rest of the way home?

Comment: http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv89.shtml

Comment: I thought he was driving to the beach?

Comment: If "long" means time, then it will take (346-180) / v, where v is average speed on his way home in miles per hour. If "long" means distance, then this is a badly phrased sentence, and the author must be persecuted by Language Police.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the "long" in the statement refers to time. Unfortunately, there's not enough information to solve that problem based off of the information given.

Unless its a typo, then the correct form of that problem would be: "Bill drives 346 miles from home to the beach. He stops for lunch after driving 180 miles. How many miles does he have left for the rest of the way home." Which could be solved with the given information.